# What is the difference between differential 1-form and duality pairing?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am trying to learn the basics of differential geometry. The duality pairing between a coordinate basis and its canonical basis is given by the Kronecker delta, which is nothing but a scalar value. Whereas, the differential 1-form in my notes is given as $\alpha = \alpha_i (x^1,...,x^n) dx^{i}$. In the above relation, am i right in assuming that $(x^1,...,x^n)$ is the vector of expansion coefficients of any tangent vector, if $\alpha_i$ are the expansion coefficients of the corresponding cotangent vector? If so, how does the relation for differential 1-form has a dimension of 1?  Also how does one physically interpret duality pairing and differential 1-form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the language: For a finite dimensional real vector space $V$, its dual space is defined as
$$V^* := \{ \alpha: V \to \mathbb R \mid \alpha \text{ is linear} \}.$$

A dual pairing is now a map 
$$<\cdot,\cdot>: V \times V^* \to \mathbb R: (v,\alpha) \mapsto \alpha(v).  $$

If $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, we call $\{ e^1, \dots, e^n\}$ the dual basis of $V^*$, if
$$ e^i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}, \text{ for all } i,j.$$

**Is $\alpha(x^1, \dots, x^n)$ the vector of expansion coefficients of any tangent vector?**

No. I would assume, that these are coefficients which depend on the current coordinates.

A differential 1-form is a smooth map $\alpha:TM \to \mathbb R$ which is linear on each fiber, i.e. at each point $p$, the restriction $\alpha_p: T_p M \to \mathbb R$ is a linear map, or equivalently $\alpha_p \in (T_pM)^* =: T^*_pM$

A given chart implies a basis of the tangent space $\left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}|_p, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}|_p\right\} \subset T_pM$ and a dual basis of the cotangent space $\left\{ dx^1_p, \dots, dx^n_p \right\} \subset T^*_p M$.

Now at each point $p$ we can find coefficients $\lambda_i(p)$, to write the covector $\alpha_p$ as a linear combination of the dual basis vectors, i.e. $\alpha_p = \sum_i \lambda_i(p)  dx^i_p.$

But these coefficients depend on the current point $p$! 
Therefore, if we want to describe $\alpha$ not only at $p$ but in the domain of a chart $x$, we may write
$$ \alpha = \sum_i \lambda_i(x^1, \dots, x^n) dx^i.$$

**Relation to the dual pairing?**

The dual pairing is already hidden in the construction of the dual basis!

For tangential and cotangential vectors, the relation between a basis and a dual basis reads
$$ dx^j\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right) = \delta_{ij}.$$

In particular 
$$\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = \sum_i \lambda_i dx^i\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right) = \lambda_j.$$

**Physical interpretation**

That's a question on its own. There are many important 1-forms in physics, for example momentum and (often) force. In physics these are usually called contravariant vectors, since they transform differently than tangent vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It makes more sense now that the expansion coefficient of co-vector is a function of the position in tangential vector space. I tend to get lost in the syntax for these expressions. Hypothetically, had it been a vector of expansion coefficients, would I represent it with $x^j$ in that case?

Comment: If you have a tangent vector $v \in TM$, you could represent it with respect to a chart $x$ via $v = \sum \mu_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \sum_i dx^i( v ) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. A bit confusing, I know...  So, if you want to get a (locally defined) chart  $TM \to \mathbb R^{2n}$, it would be $\mapsto \left(x^1(p), \dots x^n(p), dx^1(v), \dots dx^n(v)\right)$. Here $p$ is the point such that $v \in T_pM$. The expansion coefficients of $v$ with respect the chart's tangent basis are $dx^i(v)$.

Comment: Much appreciated!